# Did Muhammed (pbuh) liked some kind of music/instrument such as 'Dhab'?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, music

I came across this song

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y056_lhHUp4

In that link we find the following quote:

"It is so called dhab in arabic,as what i heard Rasullah love this type of low dhub music,pls.make it more clear with some of scholars."

I'd like to know if this is true. If Muhammed (pbuh) liked this kind of instrument/music, or any other.

Note: I am not hasking if it is halal or not.

Comment: I guess what you are asking about is duff الدف this is clearly mentioned in the sunnah as a halal instrument.